# relative path from pom.xml does not get resolved when using git

Tags: java, git, svn, maven, merge

I have a strange issue which I guess comes from git. In one of the poms in the projects I'm trying to build there's a call to some source-generator with a config-argument like `${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../resources/config/variables.properties` (Note the ../ to get to some upper directory). Everything was fine until I merged the master to the branch. This is when the build of this module started to fail with

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal some.package.maven.plugins:runtime-configs-generator:1.1:generate (generate-runtime-config) on project runtime-configs: /home/user/development/workspace_primary/configs/runtime-configs/src/main/java/../resources/config/files.properties (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]`

my setup: I'm locally using git and dcommit to a remote svn repository.

It seems like the file can't be found anymore. Strangely there are no changes in the relevant parts of the files after the merge.

I next tried to merge by using svn just to make sure the files are exactly the same as with the git merge.

Then I commited the merge I did with git to the subversion repository and did a fresh checkout using svn. It builds with no problem. However when using the git repo I still get the same error.

I tried to delete the local git branch and recreated it again from the remote refs. Still it does not build with the error. First I thought it might be an issue with my terminal/shell (terminator with zshell) having a problem with relative paths, but then why it built before the merge and why it builds from the svn checkout but not from the git directory? When I replace the relative path in the pom.xml with something like

`${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/variables.properties`

it also runs from the git directory though.
Can anyone explain this weird behavior, I'd love to understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something must have been broken in the git repo... I restored an older version from a backup, did git svn fetch && git svn rebase and it's working fine now